# summation inequlity

Tags: inequality

how to derive the following inequality:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{x_k}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_k}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}} $$

The main question is to prove $n^2 \leq (\sum_{k=1}^n x_k) (\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}) $
I understood the LHS, it is $ n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{x_k}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_k}} $

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. More explicitly,

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \sqrt{x_k}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_k}} \le \sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n (\sqrt{x_k})^2}\,\sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_k}}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n x_k}\, \sqrt{\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}.$$

Comment: ok, now I see it, so if $x = \sqrt{x_k}$ and $y = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x_k}}$
then by Cauchy Schwarz inequality 

$$|x.y| \leq ||x|| ||y||$$
The only thing I am not sure is why you explicitly used dot product on the RHS

Comment: It's not the dot product -- it's just ordinary multiplication.

Comment: I've removed that $\cdot$ and put spacing between the large square roots in the second and third steps, so you won't get confused with the dot product. Does that help?

Comment: Yep, all good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apply AM-GM inequality twice $RHS=\sqrt{\sum x_k\cdot \sum \dfrac{1}{x_k}}  \geq \sqrt{n^2\sqrt[n]{\prod x_k\cdot \prod \dfrac{1}{x_k}}} = n=LSH$.

Comment: Haven't done AM-GM inequality yet, but will look at your answer once I do that topic.